# Chrome File System Api

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a file using chrome File System Api and i am using the following code:

```
function onInitFileSystem(filesystem) {
filesystem.root.getFile('sample.txt', { create: true, exclusive: true },
function (fileEntry) {
// Do something with new file.
}, errorHandler);
}
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.Permanent, 1024 * 1024, onInitFileSystem,
errorHandler);
```

After running this code i am getting an error:
"It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources."
name:"SecurityError"

Does any one have any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SECURITY_ERR when you're trying to run your app from a file as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError). For security reasons, this is not allowed. However, this can be temporarily bypassed for testing purposes using --allow-file-access-from-files flag. Updated [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction#file) is here.

Comment: Or develop using a simple web server https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb